# Ajax not firing in IE10

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

My script works in Chrome. I had some difficulty in Edge and IE10. I have narrowed it down to the script below. After some testing it works in Edge but still not in IE10

**JS Library:**

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">`

**JS**

```
function scrollhandler() {
$.getJSON("check_time_scroll.php", function(update) {
    if (update.count===true) {
    alert("Update available");
    } 
  });
}
setInterval(scrollhandler, 10000);
```

Additional Info:
`check_time_scroll.php` check if there is any new relevant content in the database. If there is, I get a `true` and if `true` I load content to a `<div>`.

For testing purposes I have replaced the `<div>` loading script with an `alert`.

Is it possible that I am using the wrong Library? In Edge the alert test works but does not upload the content to the `<div>` with the original script.

Original script:

```
function scrollhandler() {
 $.getJSON("check_time_scroll.php", function(update) {
    if (update.count===true) {
    $("#scrolltext").load('unifoscrolltext.php');
    } 
  });
}
setInterval(scrollhandler, 10000);
```

Comment: look at your developer console

Comment: I did. That's why I said the function is not firing

Comment: Firstly, there's no HTML or PHP to support the question. This might even be PHP related. If so, check for errors via PHP.

Comment: It is not php related. Like I said, it works perfectly in Chrome.

Comment: Try attaching a [`.fail()` callback](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/) to `$.getJSON()` that logs its `arguments`. If jQuery is detecting an issue, such as being unable to parse the response from the server, it may fail silently by default.

Comment: You didn't mention whether you get an alert in IE10

Comment: @Jonathan. I get no alert in IE10

Comment: @Wienievra so stick an else in there and alert out the contents of update `else { alert(update); }` or like my doppelganger suggests, put a failure callback, heck, all the callbacks you can use and alert out the contents.

Comment: In what way isn't it working? Is it that no `alert()` appears? Are you certain `update.count` is `true`? What is the response being received? Have you attempted adding an `else` statement to see if that behavior occurs?

Comment: @Jonathan, Yes I have tried an `else` statement. In Chrome I get an alert, In IE10 I get no alert

Comment: @Wienievra and if you alert before your if statement?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Yes I have. I have tested the check_time script - `update.count` is certainly `true`

Comment: @Jonathan What will I check for with an alert before the `if`

Comment: @Wienievra you're simply checking to see if your script gets that far. I.e. if you're saying there's no else, then its highly likely your if was never reached. So alert("cheese!") before the if and we narrowed it to the method call

Comment: @Jonathan. Ahh. Make sense. Thanks. Just did and got the alert in all browsers (Cheese alert)

Comment: So can you output what you get from (before the if) `alert(update)`. You could also change the parameter from `update` to `data, status, xhr` and alert them all out. Get more clues. I think you can use `console.log()` in IE10 so you might as well start using that instead, and provide some feedback in your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the IE10 have problem with cache information.

```
function scrollhandler() {
    var d = new Date();
    var cache = d.getTime();
    $.getJSON("check_time_scroll.php?cache=" + cache, function (update) {
        if (update.count === true) {
            $("#scrolltext").load('unifoscrolltext.php?cache=' + cache);
        }
    }); 
} 

setInterval(scrollhandler, 10000);
```

Comment: Thanks !! JavaScript is not my strong point. This worked. Do you mind explaining the code?

Comment: In my opinion Microsoft is complicated to understand.
Internally when you call to $ .get ... or $ .load ... or $ .ajax this object uses proprietary ActiveXObject ("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") which is not the same as using modern browsers XMLHttpRequest () native .
By default Microsoft.XMLHTTP uses CACHE by url.
When called once myphp.php example gets the information, but in the second call in his history not call again.
Using dynamic URL example: myphp.php?cache = 12345,,, myphp.php cache?12346, myphp.php?cache=12347 it forces the object Microsoft.XMLHTTP call the url again.